# @RequestBody и обязательные/необязательные значения в JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, controller

Есть JSON:

```
{
    "rating" : 3,
    "comment" : "My comment"
}
```

При этом поле **`rating` является обязательным, а `comment` - опциональным**.

Можно ли это как-то учесть на этапе маппинга в контроллере?

```
public String putComment (@RequestBody MyObj obj) {
  return obj.toString();
}
```

Comment: Вы можете написать свой десериализатор - наследник от JsonDeserializer.

Answer (score 2):

Добавляем валидаторы:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Добавляем саму валидацию:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Controller {
    @GetMapping
    public MyObj get(@Valid @RequestBody MyObj myObj) {
        return myObj;
    }

    @Data
    private static class MyObj  {
        @NotNull
        private String title;
        private String description;
    }
}
```

Обращаю внимание, что аннотация вида `@JsonProperty(required = true)` не относится к пакету валидации запросов, поэтому работать не будет.